# Why the number of spaces inserted by M-; is less than the number of spaces in comment-start and comment-padding?

Tags: comment, whitespace

I am using `emacs -q` and editing a text buffer `foo.txt`.

I have added the following settings:

```lisp
(setq comment-start ">::")
(setq comment-padding ":::<")
```

Now if I select a region containing these lines

```
foo
bar
baz
```

and press `M-;`, I get this commented out like this

```
>:::::<foo
>:::::<bar
>:::::<baz
```

Looks fine so far. But now I change the settings to like this:

```lisp
(setq comment-start ">  ")
(setq comment-padding "   <")
```

Now if I comment the same region as earlier again with `M-q` I get:

```
>   <foo
>   <bar
>   <baz
```

But I was expecting

```
>     <foo
>     <bar
>     <baz
```

Why is the commenting prefix string `>   <` instead of `>     <`? The comment start string contributes 2 spaces and the comment padding string contributes 3 spaces. So there should have been 5 spaces. But there are only 3 spaces. Why?

Comment: `Why` questions are tricky: they can lead to a cascade of opinion-based comments/answers. In my answer I explain through the existing code why the behavior is consistent with how the code is designed, without attempting to explain why it was designed this way (apart from a guess and a suggestion of what it would require to change it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function used to construct the initial comment string is `comment-padright`. Its doc string says:

```
comment-padright is a byte-compiled Lisp function in ‘newcomment.el’.

(comment-padright STR &optional N)

Construct a string composed of STR plus ‘comment-padding’.
It also adds N copies of the last non-whitespace chars of STR.
If STR already contains padding, the corresponding amount is
ignored from ‘comment-padding’.
N defaults to 0.
If N is ‘re’, a regexp is returned instead, that would match
the string for any N.

Ensure that ‘comment-normalize-vars’ has been called before you use this.
```

It is used by `comment-region` (through its subordinate default function `comment-region-default-1` as follows:

```el
  ...
  (let ((s (comment-padright comment-start numarg)))
        ...)
    ...
```

to construct the opening string.

As the doc string states, `If STR already contains padding, the corresponding amount is ignored from ‘comment-padding’`. That explains why the extra spaces in `comment-padding` don't do anything. But why do the colons matter in the previous case? A comment in `comment-padright` itself explains that:

```el
    ...
    (if (not (string-match-p "\\`\\s-" comment-padding))
        ;; If the padding isn't spaces, then don't
        ;; shorten the padding.
        comment-padding
      (substring comment-padding ;additional right padding
                 (min (- (match-end 0) (match-end 1))
                      (length comment-padding)))))))
    ...
```

It's only spaces as padding that are discarded. See the code in [newcomment.el](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/newcomment.el#n821). The line number in this link is correct at the time of writing, but it may change in the future, so you may have to search a bit to find the `comment-padright` function.

So the behavior is as designed. *Why* it was designed this way however is another matter: I suspect that a choice was made on which reasonable people might disagree. If someone musters a compelling argument for doing it a different way, then a bug report describing the use case might cause the developers to make appropriate changes.